# threading in Python - how to wait for an unknown number of other threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I am certain there is a very easy solution to this - I just do not know where to look for it.

I have one method which does as follows:

```
 @staticmethod  
def serverstart(self):
    '''
    This binds the serverobject to a port (here: 50001) and creates a list of clients.
    For each client, a new clientthread object is created. There exist two different lists, one for the 
    sockets (literally) and one for the clientthreads
    '''
    logging.getLogger(__name__).info("Servergestartet(Verbindung usw)") 
    self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    self.server.bind(("", 50001)) 
    self.server.listen(1)
    #the list for the sockets
    self.clients = []
    #the list for the clientthreads
    self.clientthreads = []
    #hallo = "hallo" 
    self.clientnumber = 0          

    try: 
        while True: 
            lesen, schreiben, oob = select.select([self.server] + self.clients, 
                                         [], [])

            for sock in lesen: 
                if sock is self.server: 
                    client, addr = self.server.accept() 
                    myclient = clientthread.Clientthread(client, self.clientnumber, self)
                    self.clientnumber= self.clientnumber+1
                    myclient.start()
                    self.clients.append(client) 
                    self.clientthreads.append(myclient)
                    print "+++ Client %s verbunden" % addr[0] 
                #else: 
                    #nachricht = sock.recv(1024) 
                    #ip = sock.getpeername()[0] 
                    #if nachricht: 
                        #print "[%s,%d] %s" % (ip, self.clients.index(sock),nachricht) 
                    #else: 
                        #print "+++ Verbindung zu %s beendet" % ip 
                        #sock.close() 
                        #self.clients.remove(sock) 
    finally:
        logging.getLogger(__name__).info("serverstart ist durchgelaufen")
```

thus creating a new Clientthread instance whenever a new client connects.

Clientthread now inherits from Threading:

```
class Clientthread(threading.Thread):

   def __init__(self,clientsocket, clientnumber, server):

         threading.Thread.__init__(self)


       def run(self):
    from modules.logic import game
    '''
    as clientthread inherits from threading.Thread, this is this Thread's run-method.
    All it does is start the thread with the processkeysmethod - by now.
    '''
    logging.getLogger(__name__).info("Runmethode des Clientsockets läuft")
    logging.getLogger(__name__).info("Daten aus dem Client werden verarbeitet")


    while True:
        try:
            Clientthread.prepareDataforClient(self)
            Clientthread.processkeys(self)
        except Exception as e:
            print e
```

Now, of course every single instance of Clientthread works on the same global Data.

My problem is now, how can I synchronize this? As it is, there is no way for one of the Clientthreads to know how many other Clientthreads there are- technically, it can be any number from zero onwards.

Is there an easy way to solve this

Comment: Are you asking how to serialise each thread's access to the global data (i.e. to make sure only one thread at a time is reading/writing the global data)?

Comment: Imagine 3 threads: 1 starts, does the loop- and then? how  to make sure the Thread releases the global data so the next thread can work on them (writing, not just reading!) you see, before the two static methods where themselves targets to threads and contained while loops, and so they blocked one another, because they were working on the same globals. So should not several Clientthread instances block each other too?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you aware of the options for threads synchronization? For example, have you tried using a [RLock](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#rlock-objects)?

Comment: Yes, I did use that already, but I have no idea how it could work here. I did try things where I acquired and released the lock within the runmethod, but...hang on....I just got you meaning I think.

Comment: asermax I knew beforehand how RLocks work but your little comment just tore down a wall in my brain - will you not write an answer so I can value it?

Answer (score 0):

You need a mutex to sync threads' access to a shared resource. You can then use the mutex like this:

```
with mtx:
    # access shared data
```

That said, there are a few questions left:

- What exactly you needed wasn't 100% clear. If an RLock solves your problem, how does that correspond to your statement that you are writing and not just reading?
- Further, please clean up your code a bit, remove unnecessary stuff like commented code.
- The indention is off, which is a sin in Python.
- The use of @staticmethod is weird.
- Calling `ClassName.function(self)` is probably better written as `self.function()`.
- Use super() to call the baseclass' init function.
- If you have a 1:1 relation between clients and clientthreads, chances are that this is better modeled by aggregating them in a common class.

Lastly, and I'm not sure if I can explain that properly, I'd rather not derive from Thread. The object is not the thread, but represents one, similar to a file. Creating one will create a thread, but e.g. destroying one does not stop the thread, for that reason I find derivation unnatural. This then looks like this:

```
s = accept(...)
th = threading.Thread(target=connection_handler_function, args=(s,))
th.daemon = True # you probably want that
th.start()
```